# How to run autokey python script as root

Tags: python, autokey

I have a python script that requires using keyboard however it always fail to run with:

```
ImportError: You must be root use this library on linux.
```

**I do want to run it as root**, but how do I go about doing this **in autokey** (*as I need the hotkey functionality*)?

Script that triggers that error just for reference:

```
# Enter script code
import time, random, keyboard
while True:
    mouse.click_relative_self(0,0,1)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        break
```

I've already installed via pip all libraries.

Comment: try ```sudo pip3 install keyboard```

Comment: @MostafaMohamed that doesn't work, the error keeps showing. I had already installed via normal pip, but also tried with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda was looking for a GUI way to do it, but the easiest way is to just **launch Autokey in terminal like**:

```
sudo autokey
```

And just copy/paste the script in that sudoed Autokey GUI.

Of course considering all libraries are already installed via **pip**.